# how to get these XML elements with libxml2?

Tags: xml, libxml2

i have a XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root>
<item>
    <foo1>1</foo1>
    <foo2>2</foo2>
</item>
<item>
    <foo1>3</foo1>
    <foo2>4</foo2>
</item>
</root>
```

now i go throw all children with a for loop:

```
for (pCurrentElement...) {

}
```

now i want to access throw pCurrentElement the foo1 and foo2 but i dont know how.
i use **LIBXML2**

i can get foo1 with:

```
pChildElement = pCurrentElement->children->next;
pChildElement->children->content // foo1
```

but i dont know how to get foo2 now?

Answer (score 5):

By default, libxml2 parses whitespace within the document into its own child nodes. If there is whitespace in front of foo1 and foo2, then foo1 will be `pCurrentElement->children->next`, and foo2 will be `pCurrentElement->children->next->next->next`.

If you disable whitespace parsing, using either `xmlKeepBlanksDefault(0)` or `xmlReadDoc(..., XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS)`, then foo1 will be `pCurrentElement->children` and foo2 will be `pCurrentElement->children->next` instead.

Comment: I forgot that by default, libxml2 parses whitespace within the document into its own child nodes.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB Thanks for the "No blanks" option.. the default behaviour is anoying, and I couldn't find it in the docs. 
(It's Called 'no_blanks' in the Perl module btw).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`xmlNextElementSibling`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNextElementSibling). When applied to `foo1`, it gives you `foo2`.

Or loop through all the children `while (child->next)` and process only nodes of given [`type`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlElementType).

Answer (score 0):

```
pChildElement = pCurrentElement->children->next; //if this is pointing to <item>
pChildElement->children->content // foo1  // this is <item>->children->first element (which is foo1)
```

so naturally

```
pChildElement->children->next->content would be the next sibling of foo1, which is foo2
```

Comment: hm the problem is, then i always get the content '\n    '

Comment: What about pChildElement->next->children->content ?

Comment: @murtek: that is because libxml2 parses whitespace into nodes as well, which you are not taking into account.  See my other answer.